# Spring statemachine's java configuration for order shipping example

Tags: java, spring, spring-statemachine

Looking at the following example provided by spring statemachine documentation, it is loading the configuration from a UML file. Unfortunately, i am not familiar with UML so is there any link where can i find java config of states and transitions instead of UML.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/reference/#statemachine-examples-ordershipping

Answer (score 0):

[Is that what you're looking for?](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/blob/main/spring-statemachine-samples/ordershipping/src/main/java/demo/ordershipping/StateMachineConfig.java) In this example, it loads an UML property file to load the configuration, so perhaps you can see that file and try to reverse engineering what java config would look like?

All the documentation examples can be found here:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/tree/main/spring-statemachine-samples